# "mini-css-extract-plugin" every time injects a new number in main.js file on each build which changing contenthash number of main.js unnecessarily

Tags: webpack, bundling-and-minification, http-caching, mini-css-extract-plugin, webpack-splitchunks

I am using webpack 5, and using contenthash for the main.js file. But my main.js file gets a new hash number on every build even if there is nothing changed in my application. When I compared two main.js files from two different builds, then I found that the **"mini-css-extract-plugin" injects a new number in main.js file everytime on each build**. That causing to change the hash number of my main.js. I don't know why mini-css-extract-plugin is updating these numbers in my main.js file and how to stop this so that my main.js hash number doesn't get changed unnecessarily. I am attaching a comparison of two main.js files.

[image]

Any help would be appriciated. Thanks.